# "Property Not Found" Access Error When Querying With a Null Field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an odd problem with MS Access 2013 at the moment. It keeps returning "Property Not Found" when I query it with a null field.

The query I've created should allow users to enter some, all or none of a postcode and return the matching records. On my laptop (running Access 2016) this query runs fine in all forms, but returns the aforementioned error when the field is left blank.

The query (in SQL mode) is:

```
WHERE ((Left([Carer Contact Details]![Postcode],Len([Forms]! 
[AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch])))=[Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch])) OR ((([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch]) Is Null));
```

There are some extra parts to the query, relating to other parts of the form but they are not relevant here as all other parts of the query are functioning.

I suspect this is an compatibility issue between Access 2016 and 2013. The database was originally made in Access 2016, but I had to port it onto an older system which runs 2013. This is the only difference I can ascertain, and I can't figure out any other reason why it might work on one machine and not the other!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *Nz*:

```
WHERE
    (Left([Carer Contact Details]![Postcode], Len(Nz([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch]))) = Nz([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch])) 
    OR 
    ([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch] Is Null);
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav! That did the trick. Am I to assume this worked as Access was complaining about there being a Null value, whereas using Nz here makes it into a  zero-length string instead?